# How can I interpret the parameter 'width' in scipy peak detection?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I'm still not pretty sure how I can understand the parameter 'width' in detecting peaks using `scipy`. Here's a histogram I'm considering:
[image]
If I set

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(probsuc,width=4)
peak_prominences(probsuc, peaks, wlen=7)
```

Then the output looks like

```
(array([0.20229167, 0.25791667]), array([ 4, 39]), array([10, 45]))
```

However, if I set `width=5`, then there's only one peak detectable:

```
(array([0.20229167]), array([4]), array([10]))
```

And no peak could be detected if `width=6`. I'm wondering what width exactly means? (I do not quite understand the description on the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html#scipy.signal.find_peaks)) If I want to detect the two major peaks on the histogram, is there a general strategy to set the value of `width`?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` parameter tells the function to only consider a peak as a local maximum if a certain number of consecutive samples or bins exceeds the `threshold` and `height` parameters.

The number of peaks decreases as you increase the value of `width` because you are adding an increasingly stringent condition. In your example, one of the peaks is not found with `width=5` because the height of the five bins does not meet the conditions to be considered a local max.

With `width` being a hyperparameter, there is no single correct way of finding its best value. One way you could find a good `width` candidate would be to generate many sequences and manually count the number of peaks in order to create a labeled dataset. Then you could run a grid search to find the most accurate `width`, such as the width that leads to the lowest mean squared error.